# What are my best option(s) if desiring to tunnel/reverse-proxy to-and-from a telnet server?

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, telnet, reverse-proxy, relay

I have a quite small VPS abroad, and a BBS telnet server software that i wish to run locally.

What are my options, If i wish to only use the VPS as a **relay** for connections, effectively and transparently forwarding and relaying **all** port 23 and port 22 traffic, between any connecting telnet clients, *via the VPS*, and the actual computer serving/hosting the server software and storage?

- neither relay nor local server have got static public ip, *only* dynamically updated dns hostnames.
- **All** telnet (port 23) and ssh (port 22) communication, between the actual server and any clients, would have to transparently go via the VPS relay.

Shouldn't it be possible somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do that. You can set up an SSH tunnel and connect your server via SOCKS proxy, or you can create a tunnel interface (OpenVPN, for instance) and bind the server to it.

A more elegant solution might be to use NAT on your remote system:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 23 -j DNAT --to-destination <home_server_ip>:23
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

You would also need to allow IP forwarding by adding `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: Would this work well OK with UFW enabled and take presedence in IPTables ?

Comment: the '''--to-destination <home_server_ip>:23''' would have be a dynamic url unfortunately, since there's no static public ip on the home_server connection

Comment: Would the IPTables rules be transparent <client>-<vps relay>-<server> both ways?